# Changing the page-to-html XSLT in Interwoven SitePublisher

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, interwoven

In order to reduce the number of templates used in a site, I tried to expose a number of layout options in a template component. By accessing these option values from the components in the page-to-html transformation, I thought I could control the output of certain areas.

I assumed that the input to this XSLT was the page file content itself, but it seems that the components are already transformed to HTML, and thus the datum elements of each component are no longer available.

Is there a way to use a component to influence the page scope by accessing the component data or output in the page-to-html workflow in Interwoven TeamSite 6.7.2 and SitePublisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found a way around this problem.

By creating a Java class and run it in the page generation workflow, it will receive the content of the page file as input.

By reading the component data and adding these to the Page_Display_Properties element, they can be accessed in the XSLT after each component's XML is transformed.

Comment: I'd appreciate a little more info on how you did this. Did you blog about it anywhere? I'm running in to the same issues myself.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's been a while since I worked with this, and I no longer have access to the source code. I think it was a packaged named external or something, that made it possible to hook up custom classes to the page generation workflow. I'm sorry I can't be of more help. Best of luck to you :)

Comment: No problem, I ended up putting the little bit I needed in to the page context. Finally realized that the XML outside of Page_Display_Properties wasn't actually rendered at the same time the rest of the XSL runs. Annoying and, as always, undocumented.